# <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'><class 'datetime.time'> の引き算をしたい

Tags: python, pandas

python 初級者です。
`pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`と`datetime.time`の引き算をすると以下のエラーが出てしまい、引き算が出来ません。

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'
```

12:55:00 と12:56:52の引き算をして00:01:52を得るだけなのですが、恥ずかしながら苦戦しております。
工場の作業時間の分析プログラムです。
"休憩時刻end"は日付なしの定数的な時刻データ。
"作業中"は日付の付いた実績データといった感じです。

ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

---

**実際のコード**

```
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd

休憩時刻end = datetime.time(12,55,0)

作業中 = pd.Timestamp('2019-06-24 12:56:52')

td = 作業中.time()-休憩時刻end
```

Comment: [質問を再現するための動作するサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を提示してもらうとアドバイスが付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 参考: [subtract two times in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39651061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

勤務/作業/稼働など時間データの加減算は、特定の同じ型のデータの間でしか計算できません。
質問のプログラムではPython組み込みの`datetime.time`とpandasライブラリの`Timestamp`の間で計算しようとしてエラーになっています。
しかもPython組み込みの`datetime.time`は時間データの加減算が出来る型ではありません。

だいたい以下のような型で時間データの加減算が可能です。

- Python組み込みの`datetime.datetime`, `datetime.timedelta` 等
- pandasの`Timestamp`, `Timedelta`, `Timespan` 等

演算結果の型はPython組み込みなら`datetime.timedelta`、pandasなら`Timedelta`になります。

pandasだけでやるなら、以下のようになるでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd

作業中 = pd.Timestamp('2019-06-24 12:56:52')
休憩時刻end = 作業中.combine(作業中.date(), pd.Timestamp('12:55:00').time())
td = 作業中 - 休憩時刻end
print(td)
```

Python組み込みに合わせるなら、以下のようになるでしょう。

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

作業中 = pd.Timestamp('2019-06-24 12:56:52').to_pydatetime()
休憩時刻end = 作業中.combine(作業中.date(), datetime.time(12,55,0))
td = 作業中 - 休憩時刻end
print(td)
```

Comment: 大変勉強になりました。期待した出力を得ることができました。ありがとうございました。